# Using enumerations in React select

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums

I want to show a dropdown in React using the following enumeration. The idea is to prevent using random strings as keys in my `<select>`. Keys should be constrained to `Stooges.larry`, `Stooges.curly` and `Stooges.moe`:

```
const Stooges = {
  larry: "Larry Fine",
  curly: "Curly Howard",
  moe: "Moe Howard"
};
```

Here's the code for my select, which works just fine:

```
<select value={stooge} onChange={handleChange}>
  {Object.keys(Stooges).map(key => (
    <option key={key} value={key}>
      {Stooges[key]}
    </option>
  ))}
</select>
```

The problem comes in when I am trying to set the initial value of the dropdown - I have to use a hard coded key:

```
const [stooge, setStooge] = React.useState('larry');
```

I can soften this a bit by picking the first key:

```
const keys = Object.keys(Stooges);
const [stooge, setStooge] = React.useState(keys[0]);
```

However, this still feels wrong. I can't tell from `key[0]` who am I picking.

Is there a better way to deal with enumerations in this use case? I have tried string enums in TypeScript, but they have the same issue:

```
enum Stooges {
  larry = "Larry Fine",
  curly = "Curly Howard",
  moe = "Moe Howard"
}
```

Please see my CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/0yq9n1njpp).

Comment: I found out that `keyof Stooges` would only work for `type Stooges = {...}`, so I deleted my answer :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For lack of a better solution, I have taken the following approach. I am at least able to pick the right enum by name: `Stooges.larry.id`:

```
const Stooges = {
  larry: {
    id: "larry",
    name: "Larry Fine"
  },
  curly: {
    id: "curly",
    name: "Curly Howard"
  },
  moe: {
    id: "moe",
    name: "Moe Howard"
  }
};

function App() {
  const [stooge, setStooge] = React.useState(Stooges.larry.id);

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setStooge(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select value={stooge} onChange={handleChange}>
        {Object.keys(Stooges).map(key => (
          <option key={key} value={key}>
            {Stooges[key].name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's the new CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/wqj2q94o2k

Comment: using `Object.values(Stooges).map((value, index) => (...)` instead wouldn't have fixed your issue?

Answer (score 9):

For an enum `Animals`:

```
enum Animal{
  Cat= "Cat",
  Dog= "Dog",
  Hamster= "Hamster"
}
```

We can define a generic function `getEnumKeys` ,that gets the array of keys of an enum:

```
// Inspired from https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30611#issuecomment-570773496
function getEnumKeys<
    T extends string,
    TEnumValue extends string | number,
>(enumVariable: { [key in T]: TEnumValue }) {
    return Object.keys(enumVariable) as Array<T>;
}
```

We can then map through the list of keys of `Animal` returned by the `getEnumKeys` function in the select.

```
import React from "react";

enum Animal {
  Cat = "Cat",
  Dog = "Dog",
  Hamster = "Hamster"
}

export default function App() {
  const [currentAnimal, setCurrentAnimal] = React.useState<Animal>(Animal.Cat);
  return (
    <select
      value={currentAnimal}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setCurrentAnimal(Animal[e.target.value as keyof typeof Animal]);
      }}
    >
      {getEnumKeys(Animal).map((key, index) => (
        <option key={index} value={Animal[key]}>
          {key}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}

function getEnumKeys<
   T extends string,
   TEnumValue extends string | number,
>(enumVariable: { [key in T]: TEnumValue }) {
    return Object.keys(enumVariable) as Array<T>;
}
```

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-sinoussi-pr7dpf?file=/src/App.tsx:0-600

Comment: Got a typescript error unless I changed `<T>` to `<T extends Object>`

Comment: i guess, better not using the `index` as the `key`?

Comment: In this case we cannot use the `index` as a key for the enum as the only keys we can use are the ones defined in the enum itself e.g. `"Cat"`, `"Dog"` and `"Hamster"`

Comment: If you use `<T extends Object>` you lose the return type safety, I made an edit with a [suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30611) that seems to work better.

Answer (score -1):

this works for me

```
enum Theme {
  LIGHT = 'light',
  DARK = 'dark',
}
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState<Theme>(Theme.LIGHT);

  const onChange = (ev: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    const { value } = ev.target;
    setTheme(value as Theme);
  };
  return (
    <div className={`app ${theme}`}>
      <select name="theme" onChange={onChange} id="theme">
        <option value={Theme.LIGHT}>light</option>
        <option value={Theme.DARK}>dark</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: While this answer could work, it can be inferred that the OP is looking to have the enum dynamically generated